# How to change the order of boxplot in R?

Tags: r, boxplot

I need Help, I builded a boxplot graph in R, but it don not have the order I need. I need to order ascending the days. Thak you for Hekp me

I did it of next way:

````
value <- c( sample(2:5, 20 , replace=T) , sample(6:10, 20 , replace=T), 
            sample(1:7, 20 , replace=T), sample(3:10, 20 , replace=T) )
data <- data.frame(days,value)
boxplot(data$value ~ data$days)```
````

Comment: Can you please include the data for 'days'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the order of factors with the 'levels' argument in the [factor](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/factor)() function.

```
#days column is by default ordered alpabetically
data <- data.frame(days = c(rep("Monday", 20),
                            rep("Tuesday", 20),
                            rep("Wednesday", 20),
                            rep("Thursday", 20)), 
                   value = c( sample(2:5, 20 , replace=T) , sample(6:10, 20 , replace=T), 
                              sample(1:7, 20 , replace=T), sample(3:10, 20 , replace=T) ))

boxplot(data$value ~ data$days)

#change order with 'factor()' and specify order with 'levels' argument
data$days <- factor(data$days, levels = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"))
boxplot(data$value ~ data$days)
```